# How to fill missing values in categorical data?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, data-analysis, missing-data, exploratory-data-analysis

I have a dataset of 20000 employees which has following three columns with missing values:

1. Passing year of College
2. College specialization
3. Name of College

Now I have 10000 employees who never went to college. My final aim is to predict their salary.

How can I fill in missing values in this case.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing values can be dealt with number of ways, which way to follow depends on the kind of data you have.

- Deleting the rows with missing values

  Rows with more number of column values as null could be dropped. (Again what is exactly more number depends on individual use case)
- Imputing the missing vlaues with Mean / Median

  For the numerical Columns you can try replacing the missing values by taking Mean / Median of the column values.
- Most frequent Values: Applicable to your Scenario

  This method is suitable for Categorical data which i assume is your case. You can try replacing missing vlaues in all three Columns with the most frequently occuring value in the given column.

Comment: So suppose most employees in my dataset have passed their college in year 2016. So will replacing null values(meaning people who never went to college) with most frequent value make sense?

Comment: What are the other columns for which you have values? Because if there are only few columns out of which the three columns mentioned by you are having null values for a person who never went to college, then the data would not make sense because Either you will have to drop all the rows which will drop all10000 employees for whom you want to predict the salaries.

Comment: There are 10-12 more columns like department,role, last salary, date of birth, id etc. But missing values in only above 3 columns which I mentioned earlier.

Comment: Well then you can easily replace the missing values with the most frequently occuring value. That's the best apporach you can take.Values in other columns will play an essential role in making predictions.If it is in your hand to manipulate the raw data, then you can also try adding an extra category in your data. Because half of your dataset contains employees that never visited college, you can have a new category like "None" for college specialisation and Name of college. Atleast with that all those 10000 employees will be treated equally. Please accept the answer if you think it make sense

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option to consider (there are many ways to handle this kind of problem).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fruits = pd.read_csv('C:\\Fruit.csv')
fruits.head()


fruits.shape
print(fruits['fruit_name'].unique())


fruits.apply(lambda x: sum(x.isnull()),axis=0)
print(fruits.isnull().sum())
```

Result:

```
fruit_label       0
fruit_name        0
fruit_subtype    10
mass              0
width             0
height            0
color_score       0

# here's the key part of the logic
fruits = fruits.fillna(fruits.mode().iloc[0])
print(fruits.isnull().sum())
```

Result:

```
fruit_label      0
fruit_name       0
fruit_subtype    0
mass             0
width            0
height           0
color_score      0
```

Sample Data Set:

```
fruit_label fruit_name  fruit_subtype   mass    width   height  color_score
1   apple   granny_smith    192 8.4 7.3 0.55
1   apple   granny_smith    180 8   6.8 0.59
1   apple   granny_smith    176 7.4 7.2 0.6
2   mandarin    mandarin    86  6.2 4.7 0.8
2   mandarin    mandarin    84  6   4.6 0.79
2   mandarin    mandarin    80  5.8 4.3 0.77
2   mandarin    mandarin    80  5.9 4.3 0.81
2   mandarin    mandarin    76  5.8 4   0.81
1   apple   braeburn    178 7.1 7.8 0.92
1   apple   braeburn    172 7.4 7   0.89
1   apple   braeburn    166 6.9 7.3 0.93
1   apple   braeburn    172 7.1 7.6 0.92
1   apple   braeburn    154 7   7.1 0.88
1   apple   golden_delicious    164 7.3 7.7 0.7
1   apple   golden_delicious    152 7.6 7.3 0.69
1   apple   golden_delicious    156 7.7 7.1 0.69
1   apple   golden_delicious    156 7.6 7.5 0.67
1   apple   golden_delicious    168 7.5 7.6 0.73
1   apple   cripps_pink 162 7.5 7.1 0.83
1   apple   cripps_pink 162 7.4 7.2 0.85
1   apple   cripps_pink 160 7.5 7.5 0.86
1   apple   cripps_pink 156 7.4 7.4 0.84
1   apple   cripps_pink 140 7.3 7.1 0.87
1   apple   cripps_pink 170 7.6 7.9 0.88
3   orange  spanish_jumbo   342 9   9.4 0.75
3   orange  spanish_jumbo   356 9.2 9.2 0.75
3   orange  spanish_jumbo   362 9.6 9.2 0.74
3   orange  selected_seconds    204 7.5 9.2 0.77
3   orange  selected_seconds    140 6.7 7.1 0.72
3   orange  selected_seconds    160 7   7.4 0.81
3   orange  selected_seconds    158 7.1 7.5 0.79
3   orange  selected_seconds    210 7.8 8   0.82
3   orange  selected_seconds    164 7.2 7   0.8
3   orange  turkey_navel    190 7.5 8.1 0.74
3   orange  turkey_navel    142 7.6 7.8 0.75
3   orange  turkey_navel    150 7.1 7.9 0.75
3   orange  turkey_navel    160 7.1 7.6 0.76
3   orange  turkey_navel    154 7.3 7.3 0.79
3   orange  turkey_navel    158 7.2 7.8 0.77
3   orange  turkey_navel    144 6.8 7.4 0.75
3   orange  turkey_navel    154 7.1 7.5 0.78
3   orange  turkey_navel    180 7.6 8.2 0.79
3   orange  turkey_navel    154 7.2 7.2 0.82
4   lemon   spanish_belsan  194 7.2 10.3    0.7
4   lemon   spanish_belsan  200 7.3 10.5    0.72
4   lemon   spanish_belsan  186 7.2 9.2 0.72
4   lemon   spanish_belsan  216 7.3 10.2    0.71
4   lemon   spanish_belsan  196 7.3 9.7 0.72
4   lemon   spanish_belsan  174 7.3 10.1    0.72
4   lemon       132 5.8 8.7 0.73
4   lemon       130 6   8.2 0.71
4   lemon       116 6   7.5 0.72
4   lemon       118 5.9 8   0.72
4   lemon       120 6   8.4 0.74
4   lemon       116 6.1 8.5 0.71
4   lemon       116 6.3 7.7 0.72
4   lemon       116 5.9 8.1 0.73
4   lemon       152 6.5 8.5 0.72
4   lemon       118 6.1 8.1 0.7
```

Take a look at this link for more info.

https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/04/how-to-handle-missing-values-of-categorical-variables/